# cookie expires too soon -- doesn't honor expiration setting

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, cookies

Can anyone suggest why my ASP.NET-generated cookies expire in less than an hour, rather than the 14 days they are set to?

I have read other similar Stack questions, but everything I have read revolves around Session, formtickets, forms authentication, etc. This is purely a cookie question. It should have nothing to do with web.config or machine.config, and nothing to do with IIS in-memory session. Just old-fashioned cookies.

Here is my function:

```
public static void WriteCookie(string cookieName, string cookieValue, int expireDays)
{
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cookieName))
     {
          HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName, cookieValue);
          cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(expireDays);
          HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
     }
}
```

In this example I am passing in the number 14 for expire days. The cookies always expire in less than an hour (maybe only 20 minutes). It seems they're behaving just like session cookies, they're gone as soon as the session is gone. They should persist for 14 days. I'm almost ready to revert to using javascript cookies because I know those always honor expiration correctly.

Here's the code to retrieve the cookie:

```
public static string ReadCookie(string cookieName)
{
     HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[cookieName];
     return cookie == null ? string.Empty : cookie.Value;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked in your browser to see what date the stored cookie is expiring?

Comment: I just looked -- expires on August 22, 2014 as expected.

Comment: can you post the code to retrieve the cookie?

Comment: Cam: I posted the code.

Comment: Code looks fine. Are you running in private/incognito browsing mode?

Comment: No private/incognito. Maybe there's some combination of cookies that's jacking things up. It does help to know the code looks fine, I can at least rule out 1 suspect. Thank you.

Comment: Did you find source of your problem?